# App level gradle sync failed, showing error: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.1.0

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

Syncing for my app level gradle failed after I added the following lines to the build.gradle file

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
```

**Edit: Adding the following line will fix the problem**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
```

It returns the following error:

> **`Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.1.0`**

I checked my Google Play Services, Google Repository, and Android Support Repository via the SDK Manager which has Versions 49, 58, and 47.0.0, respectively, which are all updated.

I also tried adding

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.1.0'
```

but it still produces the same error.

These are some of my codes:

build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'     //to be able to use HttpClient class
   compileSdkVersion 26
   defaultConfig {
      applicationId "ph.edu.uplb.ics.opruplb"
      minSdkVersion 19
      targetSdkVersion 26
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
      testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }
   buildTypes {
      release {
          minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
   }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle(Project)

```
buildscript {

   repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
   }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
       maven {
           url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
       }
       google()
       jcenter()
   }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Look at https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android for latest version

Comment: It is working now, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.1.0

Read [**`Firebase Android Release Notes.`**](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) You should set **`firebase-core:15.0.2`**

```
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
```

Comment: Sorry I think I have overlooked that. But it is working now, thank you!

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Downgrading google gms classpath is not recommended, google recommend to use always the last version : https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/